# Isomorphic/Universal React app dependencies

Tags: reactjs, express, npm, webpack

I'm developing my first big react app, which will be served dynamically by Express, so it came to my mind, that dependencies (not devDependencies) are just Express and maybe some deployment keep-running-eternally package, but not react, redux, react-router etc, which are conventionally mentioned in package.json deps. All my app is bundled and cooked before deployment, so how correct is it to mention react related deps as dependencies in config.json?

Answer (score 0):

This library is, after I have tried several boiler plates for react server-side-rendering, the simplest! Unlike other libraries which consist a lot of complicated things at first (redux, relay, graphQL etc.,) this library gives detailed explanation on how to do isomorphic react app with the minimum set of only `react` `express` and few other necessary ones: (or course in `ES6`, too)

https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/server-side-rendering-with-react-and-express-382591bfc77c

You just need to install it:

```
npm install react-server-boilerplate --save
```

After that, build and start

```
cd react-server-boilerplate
npm install
npm run build
npm start
```

Then, use `curl` in your command line's terminal so check if it truly returns data for SSR or not :

```
curl http://localhost:8080
```

The github of that library: https://github.com/Roilan/react-server-boilerplate